# Duplicating rows n times while keeping their original order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe, let's say

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

I want to repeat each row,but I want to keep the original row order
Kind of like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

I tried index.repeat, however, I get the dataframe sorted, like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = df.reindex(np.tile(df.index, 2))
```

Or, with list multiplication:

```
out = df.reindex(df.index.tolist()*2)
```

Output:

```
  Column A  Column B
0        A         1
1        B         2
2        C         3
0        A         1
1        B         2
2        C         3
```

###### Timings

`np.tile`+`reindex` is by far the most efficient

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
n = 2 # number of iterations as n.
out = pd.concat([df] * n, ignore_index=True)
```

out

```
  Column A  Column B
0        A         1
1        B         2
2        C         3
3        A         1
4        B         2
5        C         3
```

If you want to keep original index, remove `ignore_index=True`.

Comment: I hesitated to add this as possibility, but `concat` is much more expensive. For instance with `n = 1000` this would be ~80x slower than a simple reindexing ;)